# How to remove html tags in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, html, kotlin

So I retrieved my data from API (spoonacular API), but the text concluded with HTML tags when I displayed it on my screen.

for example:

> Crockpot "Refried" Beans is a <b.>gluten free and vegan</.b>......

Any suggestions on how can I get rid of that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the solution but I don't know if it's a good or bad solution.

So, import the Jsoup library in your gradle file

```
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.15.3'
```

and write this code below

```
fun parseHtml(description: String): String{
    return Jsoup.parse(description).text()
}
```

If it's bad please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Jsoup is good html parsing library. Your solution is just fine.